# I'm trying to print a list. It gives type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a list. It gives type error.

```
buyList = ["Potato", "Suger", "Rice", "Oil", "Cake", "Biscuit"]

for i in buyList:
    if i % 2 is not 0:
        print(i, end=" ")
        i += 1
```

Error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `i` is the element of the list so it is a string (for example: "Potato") and not a number

Comment: Do, what is your question? have you done *any* debugging at all, like printing `i` and seeing what it is? Trying out the various operations with examples of that? Looking up the error messages? Please stop using StackOverflow like your personal debugging service. Also, never use `is` for equality, it is the identity operator, and this is technically wrong (although due to an implementation detail, `x is 0` will work most of the time...but not all the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to iterate using the index of the list. no need to incrementing the loop variable in `for` loop

```
In [79]: buyList = ["Potato", "Suger", "Rice", "Oil", "Cake", "Biscuit"]
    ...:
    ...: for i in range(len(buyList)):
    ...:     if i % 2 != 0:
    ...:         print(buyList[i], end=" ")
    ...:
Suger Oil Biscuit
```

One more way is to use `enumerate` which gives index + value.

```
In [80]: buyList = ["Potato", "Suger", "Rice", "Oil", "Cake", "Biscuit"]
    ...:
    ...: for index, value in enumerate(buyList):
    ...:     if index % 2 != 0:
    ...:         print(value, end=" ")
    ...:
Suger Oil Biscuit
```